# HQL Date difference in minutes

Tags: java, sql, hql

I have an Entity class Foo

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
   @Basic
   @Column("Date_From)
   Date dateFrom;
   //...
}
```

I need to take difference between `date_From` and current date, then get `mod` of them.

In sql it would be

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ct.dateFrom, :date) % 120
```

But HQL does not support `DATEDIFF` function, I've tried to add it to dialect

```
registerFunction("DATEDIFF_MINUTE", new SQLFunctionTemplate(new CalendarDateType(), "DATEDIFF(minute, ?1,?2)"));
```

And use it `MOD(DATEDIFF_MINUTE(ct.dateFrom, :date), 120)`, but I get exception

```
No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 +-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
 |  +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'DATEDIFF_MINUTE' {originalText=DATEDIFF_MINUTE}
 |  \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
 |     +-[DOT] DotNode: 'Foota0_.Date_From' {propertyName=dateFrom,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=dateFrom,path=ct.dateFrom,tableAlias=Foota0_,className=ru.package.Foo,classAlias=ct}
 |     |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: '(Foota0_.Date_Create, Foota0_.User_Create)' {alias=ct, className=ru.package.Foo, tableAlias=Foota0_}
 |     |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'dateFrom' {originalText=dateFrom}
 |     \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=date, expectedType=null}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. Seems like Hibernate does not accept **camelCase** and **CAPSED_TEXT**. Renaming function to `datediff_min` worked.